# How to send Notification from FirebaseMessagingService in Android

Tags: android, firebase, broadcastreceiver, firebase-cloud-messaging

There are lot of questions already available on SO about this topic and I am not saying that I am doing something unique.

In my `FirebaseMessagingService`, I am sending Broadcast to show Notification when data message is received.

Here is my code:

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        String topic = remoteMessage.getData().get(AppConstants.Notification.TOPIC);
        if(topic != null) {
            switch (topic) {
                case FirebaseUtils.TopicMessaging.TOPIC_TASK:
                    String assignedTo = remoteMessage.getData().get(AppConstants.Notification.ASSIGNED_TO);
                    //String empId = remoteMessage.getData().get(AppConstants.Notification.EMP_ID);
                    //String assignedBy = remoteMessage.getData().get(AppConstants.Notification.ASSIGNED_BY);
                    String title = remoteMessage.getData().get(AppConstants.Notification.TITLE);
                    String body = remoteMessage.getData().get(AppConstants.Notification.BODY);
                    if (assignedTo.equals(FotApplication.Employee.Id)) {
                        //sendNotification(body, title);
                        Intent intent = new Intent("MY_INTENT_FILTER");
                        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.Notification.ASSIGNED_TO, assignedTo);
                        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.Notification.TITLE, title);
                        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.Notification.BODY, body);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
                        sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }

                    break;
             }
        }
    }
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<receiver
        android:name=".NotificationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MY_INTENT_FILTER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**NotificationReceiver**

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent != null){
        String body = null, title = null;
        if(intent.hasExtra(AppConstants.Notification.BODY)){
            body = intent.getStringExtra(AppConstants.Notification.BODY);
        }
        if(intent.hasExtra(AppConstants.Notification.TITLE)){
            title = intent.getStringExtra(AppConstants.Notification.TITLE);
        }
        if(body != null && title != null) {
            sendNotification(context, body, title);
        }
    }
}

private void sendNotification(Context context, String message, String title) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        NotificationChannel channel;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
                    "Task",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription("Task Channel");
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_new)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 500})
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE** I have tried everything from sending **notification** from FCM Json to receive it in `FirebaseMessagingService` but when App is closed (closed mean neither in Foreground nor Background) then notifications did not show up. Though data message is delivered to System tray.

The last thing I am trying to do is sending Broadcast but that's not working as well. Might be my bad. I have gone through several links and implemented every solution but that Notification thing haven't shown up anywhere. Don't know how big giants (WhatsApp, Facebook, Microsoft, Google) are doing it.

- [How to Send BroadCast from one app to another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492790/how-to-send-broadcast-from-one-app-to-another-app)
- [Why is my broadcast receiver not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007421/why-is-my-broadcast-receiver-not-working)
- [Broadcast and Broadcast receiver](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/broadcasts-and-broadcast-receivers)
- [FCM Messaging Concept](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options)
- [Firebase cloud messaging notification not received by device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351354/firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-not-received-by-device)
- [enter link description here](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/182)

Is there any workaround then let me know!

Comment: even i was looking for a proper answer to this..question..especially for `oreo` where implicit broadcast is not allowed to launch `contentIntent` (y)

Comment: yup, oreo faile generate notification in status bar